# Nested parallel regions in OpenMP and gfortran

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I am trying a very simple openmp fortran program as I have problems with nested parallel regions. The code is as follows:

```
PROGRAM TEST_OPENMP
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: omp_get_num_threads, omp_get_thread_num
CALL omp_set_num_threads( 4 )
WRITE(*,*) "I am the master thread"
!$OMP PARALLEL
write(*,*) "Hello, I am in the first parallel region", omp_get_thread_num()
!$OMP PARALLEL
write(*,*) "I am a nested parallel region : ", omp_get_thread_num()
!$OMP END PARALLEL
!$OMP END PARALLEL
write(*,*) "The master thread is back: serial region", omp_get_thread_num()
END PROGRAM TEST_OPENMP
```

I expected to have 4 instances of the string starting as "Hello, I am in..." and 16 of "I am a nested..." but what I get is the following:

```
I am the master thread
Hello, I am in the first parallel region           3
Hello, I am in the first parallel region           2
Hello, I am in the first parallel region           1
I am a nested parallel region :            0
I am a nested parallel region :            0
Hello, I am in the first parallel region           0
I am a nested parallel region :            0
I am a nested parallel region :            0
The master thread is back: serial region           0
```

Therefore the second parallel region is treated as linear. I am compiling with ´gfortran -fopenmp filename´. Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: Is it the same regardless of omp_nested?

Comment: Thanks from an openmp newbie for the (very) useful tip.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention. You can append a specific version tag, but that is not really necessary here, your code is not specific to the old Fortran 90.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the tip Tim. I was using a tutorial that didn't mention OMP_NESTED. Sorry for the dumb question.

Now it works smoothly:

```
$ export OMP_NESTED=True
$ gfortran -fopenmp openmp_example_3.f90
$ a.out 
I am the master thread
Hello, I am in the first parallel region           0
Hello, I am in the first parallel region           3
I am a nested parallel region :            0
I am a nested parallel region :            2
Hello, I am in the first parallel region           2
I am a nested parallel region :            1
Hello, I am in the first parallel region           1
I am a nested parallel region :            3
I am a nested parallel region :            0
I am a nested parallel region :            1
I am a nested parallel region :            1
I am a nested parallel region :            0
I am a nested parallel region :            1
I am a nested parallel region :            3
I am a nested parallel region :            2
I am a nested parallel region :            3
I am a nested parallel region :            0 
I am a nested parallel region :            2
I am a nested parallel region :            3
I am a nested parallel region :            2
The master thread is back: serial region           0
```